# Xorg screen detection for second seat

Tags: xorg, lightdm, xorg.conf, multiseat

On my X11 kiosk system with two separate monitors assigned to a seat each, the second monitor cannot find a corresponding screen.

Here my [Xorg.conf](https://pastebin.com/raw/5j0kz1SB).

- The [Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/raw/SQphfJEy) detected the server layout assigned to the seat, and graphical output (lightdm) is shown on the screen.
- The [Xorg.1.log](https://pastebin.com/raw/b28wbE2V) detected the server layout as well, but it fails later with

> Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.

These are the lines which start the x servers fvrom lightdm.

`/usr/bin/X -core  -novtswitch -sharevts :0 -layout
Seat0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch`

`/usr/bin/X -core -novtswitch -sharevts :1 -layout Seat1 -seat seat-1 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:1 -nolisten tcp`

I am curious about your questions and hints.